# Oracle Container Registry Kubernetes Images Not Found

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have accepted oracle license for Kubernetes images in Oracle Container Registry.
But When I am trying to pull kubernetes images, getting error image not found.

```
root@i:~# docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/kubernetes/kube-apiserver-amd64
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository container-registry.oracle.com/kubernetes/kube-apiserver-amd64
Error: image kubernetes/kube-apiserver-amd64:latest not found
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in kubeadm-registry.sh script where image tag is mentioned as 1.8.4 and in Oracle container Registry it is v1.8.4. I had to modify the script.